# .NET Application compatible with both standalone Windows and Azure

Tags: windows, azure

I need to design an MVC 2 or 3 app to work on both internal Win server and on Azure. The only problem I see is with the data storage. The app listens to some very chatty data feeds, like 10GB a day, and will have to write that data. So I'm looking for a way to have both Azure table and some other DB with minimal differences in code.

Any suggestions for what DB to use?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using flat file system locally and Blob in the cloud?

This approach works quite well for storing a lot of data (without bothering with the scalability). For indexes you can use file-based [SQlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (works perfectly in Azure), and for actual serialization - Open Source [ProtoBuf.NET](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) (Fasted and most compact serialization for .NET).

> NB: If your system uses patterns from the [CQRS Architecture](http://abdullin.com/cqrs/) approach, then it's much easier to pick persistence type that's make the most sense in your case.